# Verify my solution of $y'=(1-y)\sqrt{y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve

$$y'=(1-y)\sqrt{y},\ \ \  y(0)=y_0$$

My approach:
$$\begin{align}
\int{\frac{1}{(1-y)\sqrt{y}}dy}=x+c\\
2\int{\frac{1}{1-w^2}dw}=x+c\\
2\text{arctanh}\sqrt{y}=x+c\\
y=\tanh^2{\frac{x+c}{2}}
\end{align}$$

So that
$$y(0)=y_0=\tanh^2{\frac{c}{2}},\  \ \ c=2 \text{arctanh}\sqrt{y_0}$$

And so the solution is
$$y=\tanh^2(\text{arctanh}\sqrt{y_0}+\frac{x}{2})$$
However, I'm a bit uncomfortable with the fact that for $|y_0|>1$  the $\text{arctanh}\sqrt{y_0}$ will be imaginary. It is not quite clear to me why (or even IF) the solution will be real?

Comment: Is this equation rise from a real application  ?

Comment: @daryakhosrotash I have no reason to expect so, it's just a question on a test about differential equations.

Comment: Using the always valid primitive $$\int\frac2{1-w^2}dw=\log\left|\frac{1+w}{1-w}\right|+C$$ instead of the conditional arctanh formula, one gets, for every nonnegative $y_0$, $$y(x)=\left(\frac{(\sqrt{y_0}+1)e^x+\sqrt{y_0}-1}{(\sqrt{y_0}+1)e^x-\sqrt{y_0}+1}\right)^2.$$ To sum up, indeed the solution is real valued, as every solution of every real differential equation with real valued initial condition (one does not leave the real line to jump into the complex domain by magic...).

Comment: @daryakhosrotash I fail to understand your question.

Comment: @Did Thanks, that's nice. However, is $$\int \frac{1}{1-w^2}dw=\text{arctanh}w$$ not also always valid?

Comment: Of course not, try w=2.

Comment: @Did Hm yes ofcourse. But then what's wrong with the reasoning
$$\int \frac{1}{1-w^2}dw=\int \frac{1}{(iw)^2+1}dx=\frac{1}{i}\arctan(iw)=\text{arctanh}(w)$$

Comment: If one looks carefully at the meaning of $\text{arctanh} w$ when $w$ is real and $|w|>1$, one gets, say, for $w>1$, $$2\text{arctanh} w=\log\left(\frac{w+1}{w-1}\right)+i\pi+2k\pi$$ for some integer $k$ hence, for $w>1$ and $v>1$, $$2(\text{arctanh} w-\text{arctanh} v)=\log\left(\frac{w+1}{w-1}\right)-\log\left(\frac{v+1}{v-1}\right),$$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the question of how to write the antiderivative, but another issue: when separating the variables, you'll have to treat the cases $y_0=1$ and $y_0=0$ separately (since you're dividing by zero in those cases).

Moreover, the solution in the case $y_0=0$ is not unique; one option is $y(x)=0$ for all $x \ge 0$,
but you can also have
$y(x)=0$ for $0 \le x \le x_0$ and $y(x)=\tanh^2(\tfrac12 (x-x_0))$ for $x>x_0$,
where $x_0 \ge 0$ is an arbitrary number. That is, the solution can stay at zero for as long as it likes, and then "take off" all of a sudden!